# Nothing can be resolved in build.sbt and plugins.sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have set up a Scala SBT project in Intellij.
However, nothing in `build.sbt` and `plugins.sbt` is resolved.

The project structure looks like this:
[image]

`build.sbt` for instance looks like this:

[image]

Why is this occuring?

Comment: Do you have the Scala plugin installed?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ and have you tried refreshing the sbt project?

Comment: Post your project/plugin.sbt file too. Also, please, edit your question to post code as plain text instead of a print screen.

Comment: @soong yes.
yw3410 15 Community Edition, yes.
 marcospereira my idea was to highlight that every line causes an error

Answer (score 0):

I have seen IntelliJ choke on sbt projects and just drawing everything in red. I don't know what triggered that, but in those cases, I

- quit IntelliJ
- deleted the `.idea` project folder
- created a fresh project from the sbt build

Then it always resolved this. In the latest version of the IntelliJ plugin, two projects are created per sbt build, like `myname` and `myname-build`. The second one is the sbt build if I'm not mistaken, and you must make sure that both are checked when importing the project in IntelliJ.

Comment: Does your project compile from the shell, like `sbt compile`?

Comment: No, I get: `Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in` and `org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.11, _2.12.0-M3`

Comment: Actually, I solved it changing the `build.sbt` code to `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.8"
)`. I understood that beause of your question. Thank you!  I have no idea why this is working now and it wasn't working before.

Comment: That warning says you are mixing libraries that depend on different incompatible versions of Scala (2.11.x and 2.12-Milestone). If this is a regular project you shouldn't need to draw in any library version that uses an unreleased (2.12) Scala version. This will cause problems at runtime. I recommend to run the [dependency-tree](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plug-in to analyse where these versions come from.